# How to get specific values from query array, using arguments

Tags: joomla-3.x, php

I am probably over thinking this. I am building a module that should get values from the content table. Currently (I have tried many different variations) I am using:

```
<?php
class getIt
{
    //Query our content table using the built in JFactory class, and loadAssocList() function. 
    // this function returns an indexed array of objects from the table
    public function getMainQuery()
    {   
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query->select($db->quoteName(array('id', 'title', 'introtext', 'images', 'fulltext')));
        $query->from($db->quoteName('#__content'));
        $query->where($db->quoteName('state') . ' = '. $db->quote('1'));
        $query->order('ordering DESC');
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $res = $db->loadAssocList();

        foreach ($res as $row)
        {
            foreach ($row as $innerRow => $value)
            {
                print_r($innerArray,$value);
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Ultimately I wan to get the results via:

```
$list = new getIt();
print_r($list->getMainQuery(2,4));
```

Where `2 and 4 == $arg1, $arg2`. I can't figure how to properly assign variables to the array values in the loop.

Comment: What is 2 and 4 in your example?

Comment: I could post an answer based on wild assumptions of what I think you want, but I think I'll vote to close as Unclear and hope that you will improve this abandoned question.  I don't know if you want to pass an array as one argument, or if you want to pass two atguments that are integers.   I don't know how you want to use the variables in your method/query.

Answer (score 1):

I may not be understanding you correctly, but you just want a specific value?  Then use loadObject();

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('state');
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__content'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('id')." = ".$db->quote('1'));

$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->loadResult();
print_r($result);
```

In this I am selecting the state value where the id is === to 1.

Comment: Thank you, and my apologies, new to PHP. I wasn't sure what terms to use.  What I want is to define arguments that I can just pass to the instantiated variable, that are dynamic to the array variables. Basically, I can build on the fly vars, for the array values, I am just lost on how to say "hey in this array, I want the value associated with Key->3->val->index. If that makes any more sense.

Comment: `echo $res->state;` won't return anything as `state` it hasn't been defined in the `select` clause ;)

Comment: Correct and updated. Not easy answering Q&A from your phone.